# Magento: Proper way to show some elements in multiple specific categories without using elseif

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently using this loop to show some elements in a specific category

```
 <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 3):?>
```

What is the proper way to add more categories? Because I tried this

```
 <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 3,4,5,6,7):?>
```

And this

```
 <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 3 || 4 || 5:?>
```

But I got a fatal error.

The only way I can think of is using elseif:

```
 <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 3):?>
 <?php elseif(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 4) { ?>
 blah blah blah
 <? } then another elseif if I want to show it in more categories ?>
```

But is there a shorter version of this? Like including all the category IDs in one line. I just want to show "blah blah blah" if the category is 3 or 4 or 5 or 6, but in just one line, without using elseif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in_array():

```
<?php

$acceptable_categories = array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
$current_category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();

if(in_array($current_category_id, $acceptable_categories)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And here's the official docs for this function: [PHP function in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much chjohasbrouck!

Answer (score 2):

Using in_array() will tidy up your code. However I wouldn't hard-code category id into the template. It will make maintenance very difficult. (consider the case where you want to add more category).
For that purpose in the template I will add:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('block.name');
```

in the content block
Then Admin => Catalog => Manage Category, select Custom Design tab and under Custom Layout Update, add:

```
<reference name='content'>
  <block type='core/template' name='block.name' template='[yourthemepath]/your-block.phtml'> </block>
</reference>
```

This way in the future if you change your mind you can just simply go to the Magento admin, no code change required.

Comment: Ohh.. I never thought of this. Thansk for this tip. :D

Comment: Btw, I implemented your suggestion, and you're right, it's better than hard coding the category IDs. :D Thanks again William! :)

Comment: Hi William Tran, maybe you're familiar with this problem. The block that I added in the category page sidebar was working fine now but I also want it to appear in the search results left sidebar. I think I did everything right, but it's still not working. I have posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901033/custom-block-and-magento-search-results-sidebar

I hope you know what's the cause and what's the solution regarding my problem. :(