# Custom Block and Magento Search Results Sidebar

Tags: xml, magento

I have a custom block that I added in the left sidebar of specific category pages in my store. Like this:

```
 <reference name="left">
   <block type='core/template' name='tenants' template='powerplantstores/tenants.phtml'></block>
 </reference>
```

I also want that specific block to appear in my search results page, thus I modified catalogsearch.xml in my layouts folder, then added:

```
 <reference name="left">
   <block type='core/template' name='tenants' template='powerplantstores/tenants.phtml'></block>
 </reference>
```

Right after

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
    <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
    <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

But the block is not appearing. And my search results page didn't display any results at all. Only the left and right sidebar, which is odd, because I only use 2 column layout with left sidebar only.

I hope a Magento expert here can enlighten me of where I went wrong.... :(

Comment: hi, just a wild guess but can you try removing <update handle=''>, cause what you want is 2 column left right ?

Comment: Wow that worked like magic. I never thought that the solution is just right in front of me. Hahahahaha! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either remove `<update handle="page_two_columns_right">` or switch to `page_two_columns_left` and remove the rest:

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

This is because method setTemplate is already called in page_two_columns_left. Leaving it there wouldn't hurt but not necessary.

Comment: Both worked. Change it to left, and removing it. I ended up change it to left. Hahaha! Thanks again William Tran. You're a true Magento genius! :D

Comment: Thanks :D, it takes a while to get use to how layout in Magento works but when it clicks you will feel much more comfortable

Comment: Thanks again William. Btw, I have ea weird problem here that no one answered. Maybe you know what's the reason why the second column is not showing: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922226/magento-table-head-colums-in-product-review-block-checkout

Comment: Hi Again William. Have you encountered this problem before?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939764/magento-shopping-cart-not-clearing-after-checkout

Nobody seems to find a solution for this problem yet in stackexchange. T__T

Answer (score 1):

As you are    using  2columnleft layout,you need to use  set handler 2colouns-left .

Change

```
<update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
```

to

```
<update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
```

Comment: how's this answer better than mine? (saying this not for the points but for the sake of those who come and read this later?)

Comment: You're answer is better. I thought I can check two answers, but the check transferred. :)) Then I transferred it again to your answer. :D