# Magento table head colums in product review block checkout

Tags: php, html, xml, magento

Has anyone here encountered this strange problem in the reivew/info.phtml template of Magento's checkout page. I have 5 table head titles in the source code namely items, description, price, quantity and subtotal:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>  
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th>           
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

But when I view my checkout page, the second th disappears. I inspected the element, maybe it was just hidden via CSS, but it isn't. Only 4 th titles appear in my checkout product reviews block, as seen in the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXanf.png

As you may have noticed, the description title is gone. But here's the catch, when I move the price right below the item, for instance like this:

```
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>  
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th>           
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

The description column will suddenly show, and the price column will disappear. Strange, but yeah, it's really strange. Something is keeping the second column from showing and I don't know what it is.

I hope some Magento expert here can enlighten me of how to show the second tr th column of review/info.phtml.

UPDATE: For the meantime, I did this:

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>  
 <th></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th>           
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
```

Notice an empty th after the item. That will not show up in the HTML output because it's on the second column (that I don't know why it's not showing up). Everything is now displaying fine. The first, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns. Hahaha.. Weird... O__O

Comment: Nevermind, I already resolved it by another another th after the first th. I still don't know what it's not appearing, but at least it was resolved for now. O_O

Comment: My best guest would be to look into decorateTable('checkout-review-table') (you will find this in review/info.phtml) to see if it's responsible.

Comment: If you output HTML you need to HTML-encode the strings. Perhaps not your issue but for sure wrong in the code-example you give.

Comment: @hakre - what I did is added a blank th after the item. And that resolved everything for now. O__O

Comment: @WilliamTran there's no decorateTable inside, which is weird. Hmmmm..

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I already resolved it by another another th after the first th. I still don't know what it's not appearing, but at least it was resolved for now. O_O

For the meantime, I did this:

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>  
 <th></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></th>           
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
```

Notice an empty th after the item. That will not show up in the HTML output because it's on the second column (that I don't know why it's not showing up). Everything is now displaying fine. The first, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns. Hahaha.. Weird... O__O

Comment: "I still don't know" is not quite an answer :) Leave that as a comment or put into your answer what you did change that *directly* resulted into the (intended) output.

Comment: I just added my quick and dirty solution. :D