# Magento Shopping Cart Not Clearing after Checkout

Tags: php, magento

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I found a similar question in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21635/why-is-shopping-cart-not-emptied-after-placing-an-order, but it's not resolved. Maybe someone here knows a solution to my problem.

After I checkout and place an order, the item remains in the shopping cart, which is really weird. This happens when a user is logged in, but when a guest checks out, the cart is emptied automatically.

I didn't encounter this in my other Magento sites with the same version (Magento 1.9). I think there's a setting somewhere in the admin that resulted to this issue.

My caching is on, an persistent cart is off. If I turn off or on both or vice versa, nothing happens, the item remains in the cart after I placed an order.

Comment: are you using file session storage ?

Comment: How can I check if I'm using it? O__O I'm not sure...

Comment: Here's my demo site: http://huawei.jehzlau.net/ if you're registered then you added an item in a cart, and placed an order, the item remains in the cart. But if you're a guest, the problem will not occur. Only if registered. :(

Comment: Hi, could you give this a try. http://tosbourn.com/deleting-magento-session-files/

Comment: also check for permission on the session folder to make sure Magento can read and write to it

Comment: I can't find my session folder. Hmmm.. And another weird thing that I found out is that specific magento site creates cache folders with different folder names, I didn't see this in my other Magento sites.

Aside from the var/cache folder, there's a var/cacheasdfasdf and var/cachegklsjfsdfs

Something like that. Random letter after cache. O__O

Comment: I think my sessions are stored in the db, I'll try to clear the logs in the database then try placing an order again. O__O

Comment: Just FYI - you can quickly verify whether sessions are stored in file or db by checking the config setting at the bottom of app/etc/local.xml

Comment: I had kind of similar problem (but more serious, customer logged in as different user), with redis cache, so keep me posted

Comment: Oh maybe it's with the cache. I cleared the DB sessions logs, and the problem still persists. Kinda weird though because other magento sites on the same server didn't encounter this problem. I'll try with a new magento install, then just migrate the theme I'm using, I think this will resolve the issue, hahaha! :D

Comment: I migrate the magento site with the cart not clearing issue to another server, and the problem is still there. Hmmmmm... I'll try another way around to catch the culprit... :D

Comment: Just updated my theme at the bag clears out. I think this is a bug with the theme or the one page checkout that I'm using. :D

Comment: And now I used the same theme, but disabled my onestepcheckout extension from facile, and the cart cleared after checkout. I think the extension is the culprit. :D

Comment: Now the cart clears after removing the extension. I just reported it to the extension developer so that they can check and see. :D

Comment: @WilliamTran - I almost fixed it. Just implement a solution I found in stackoverflow, but now I cannot see the item image and item name. I posted a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974306/item-names-disappear-on-checkout-in-magento

Maybe you know the solution.